# Check string (more than one word) for an array item

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string (more than 1 word) and an array and i want to check the string and find if the string contains any string from the array.

I have tried to use include method but it works if my matching string is only one word. 
for example

```
var arr = ['2345', '1245', '0987'];
var str = "1245"
console.log(str.includes('1245'));
```

This will work but I want to match it with a sentence.

```
var arr =  ['2345', '1245', '0987'];
var str= "Check if the number 1245 is present in the sentence."
```

I want to check if this number is present in the string.

Comment: `arr.some(it => str.includes(it))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the array.

```js
var arr =  ['2345', '1245', '0987'];
var str= "Check if the number 1245 is present in the sentence."

console.log(arr.some(x => str.includes(x)));
```

If you want to check only the words which are separated by whitespace then use split and then use `includes()`

```js
var arr =  ['2345', '1245', '0987'];
var str= "Check if the number 1245 is present in the sentence."
let parts = str.split(' ')
console.log(arr.some(x => parts.includes(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.some` combined with `String.prototype.indexOf`:

```js
var a =  ['2345', '1245', '0987'];
var s = "Check if the number 1245 is present in the sentence.";
var t = "No match here";



function checkIfAnyArrayMemberIsInString(arr, str) {
  return arr.some(x => str.indexOf(x) !== -1);
}

if (checkIfAnyArrayMemberIsInString(a, s)) {
  console.log('found');
} else {
  console.log('not found');
}

if (checkIfAnyArrayMemberIsInString(a, t)) {
  console.log('found');
} else {
  console.log('not found');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var arr =  ['2345', '1245', '0987'];
var str= "Check if the number 1245 is present in the sentence."


let found = (str) => arr.find(e => {
  return str.includes(e)
}) || `${str} Not found in searched string`

console.log(found(str))
console.log(found('878787'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
function matchWord(S, A) {
  let matchesWord = false
  S.split(' ').forEach(word => {
    if (A.includes(word)) matchesWord = true;
  });
  return matchesWord;
}

console.log(matchWord('Check for the number 1245', ['2345', '1245', '0987']))
```